# new File() works but getResource()/getResourceAsStream() throws null exception

Tags: java, eclipse, image

In the context of a school project i'm currently working on a little game in eclipse which I want to convert into an executable JAR when I'm done. Since I'm working with the .drawImage() method on my label I need to use BufferedImage or Image. To import my pictures into my project I've created a folder called "rsc" and set it as a resource folder, them put the images in there.

Now, when I use
BufferedImage bg1 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg"));
Everything works fine. But I obviously can't use that when exporting the project because that will change the paths and the method will no longer be able to find the images even though they are clearly included in the JAR (I've checked)

The resolution I found on the Internet is to use .getResource() or .getResourceAsStream()
I've tried tons of different variations. Here a few examples:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg"))

ImageIO.read(Var.class.getResourceAsStream("rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg"))

ImageIO.read(Var.class.getResource("rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg")) 

And also different path variations such as:

"/rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg" 
"rsc/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg" 
"/BlackWhiteSpace.jpg" 
"BlackWhiteSpace.jpg"
```

Etc.

I've also thought of case sensitivity and those examples aren't the only variations I've tried.

Now why is java still giving me:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

???

What am I doing wrong? This project is being graded so I really wanna be able to run it without eclipse, please help!

Edit:

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIlz4.png

https://pastebin.com/s7Yxtw6Y

Comment: Please show the (relevant parts of the) directory structure of your project. Additionally show the class (incl. the package declaration) where you are trying to load your resource file.

Comment: Game (Project) > src > contents > Var ( class) is where the class is located. The images are in Game > rsc. Here's a pastebin link to the whole class: https://pastebin.com/s7Yxtw6Y

Comment: I can't believe moving the folder into the package was all I had to do. Thank you so much!